# how to set maxHeight on a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I don't want to limit the number of lines, I want to limit the `TextInputLayout` maximum height such that if it's too long it becomes vertically scrolling.

I'm fine with in code solutions.

currently `maxHeight` attribute has no effect either on `TextInputLayout` or `EditText`.

Here is my layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="@string/address"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_8">

    <com.mamamia.mamamiarestaurant.ui.MultiLineTextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="@integer/address_max_length" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And I include it in a constraint layout

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_address"
    layout="@layout/view_text_input_layout_address"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp" />
```

`layout_constraintHeight_max` has no effect. but `layout_constrainedHeight` if set to true will make the layout fixed height (not the one specified by `layout_constraintHeight_max` but the fixed default edit text height)

Comment: Thanks, your question worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

`layout_constraintHeight_max` does not work if the view does not have top or bottom constraints, so you can either put `android:maxHeight` on the `InputEditText`, or adjust the constraints on `TextInputLayout`:

```
<include
        layout="@layout/view_text_input_layout_address"
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp" />
```

You probably only need `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` if the parent has a height of `match_parent`.